# Independent events - geometric/arithmetic mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am solving some probability theory problems and I met this problem.

Let

$A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ be independent events such that

$P(A_i) > 0$ for all $i$

and also

$$P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 \tag{$***$} $$

Prove that:

$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots\cap A_n) \le n^{-n}$$

I was not able to solve it (even though this problem was not even considered "hard" by the book I am reading) and so I went on and looked up the solution.

The solution they provide is very simple (I thought of using this trick of course but it simply didn't work for me). The solution simply uses the inequality between the geometric and arithmetic means (for the numbers $P(A_i),$ where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$). But before applying the inequality, they say that:

$$P(A_1) + P(A_2) + \cdots + P(A_n) = 1 \tag{$*$} $$

They say it follows from $(***)$. I don't see how it follows from there.

I think:

(1) either this solution is completely flawed or

(2) maybe one can still use the simple trick with the inequality between the geometric and arithmetic means but there are some deeper reasons by which $(*)$ follows from $(***)$ and maybe also from the fact that the events are independent.

I personally even tried to construct some discrete model with such evens $A_i$ that satisfy all the conditions given here but I was not able to construct one so far.

What do you think of this?

I have no one to ask so I rely on your input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right) = 1,$ then $P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n (\text{not } A_i) \right) = 0,$ so, since they are independent, $P(\text{not }A_1) \cdots P(\text{not } A_n) = 0,$ and that implies that at least one of them has probability $0.$

Since they seem to say that the sum of the probabilities is $1$ and that that follows from the fact that the probability of the union is $1,$ one must suspect that instead of saying they are independent, it said they are pairwise mutually exclusive. That would imply that $P(A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n)=0.$

Comment: But if they meant mutually exclusive... then they are extremely dependent, and then we do not have $P(A_1, A_2, ..., A_n) = P(A_1) P(A_2) ... P (A_n) $. Which means from the problem is not left much. Even your suggestion doesn't quite fit. Something is completely wrong with this problem. Also, the problem explicitly says that $P(A_i) > 0$.

Comment: Definitely something is wrong with it, the way it's stated here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of independent, they probably meant to say mutually exclusive; otherwise, take $A_i = \Omega$; then, $A_i$ are all trivially independent, and the inequality given is violated.

Comment: But if they meant mutually exclusive... then they are extremely dependent, and then we do not have $P(A_1, A_2, ..., A_n) = P(A_1) P(A_2) ... P (A_n) $. Which means from the problem is not left much.

Comment: Yeah; if they are mutually exclusive, you don't even need AM-GM inequality; that intersection is trivially 0; if you are quoting the problem in verbatim, I agree that something seems off.